# Read contents of KML file into C# Application

Tags: c#, kml

I am trying to extract Area_No, Dateof, Location, Week and the coordinates from the following KML file into a C# Windows Form Application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.test.net">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="LOC2018" id="LOC2018">
<SimpleField name="AREA_NO" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="DATEOF" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="LOCATION" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="Week" type="string"></SimpleField>


</Schema>
<Folder><name>LOC2018</name>
<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle> 
<fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#LOC2018">
    <SimpleData name="AREA_NO">1</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="DATEOF">1899/12/30</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="LOCATION">TEST ROAD</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="Week">Week1</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
 <MultiGeometry><Polygon><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode> 
 <outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode> 
<coordinates>18.672267,-4.158488 16.494032,-2.401444 
16.494032,-2.401444</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon> 
</MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

I am new to working with these files and have tried a few options that I have found on this site to no avail.

I can load the file and see the nodes, but cannot access the items in SchemaData or coordinates.

The code I have so far is:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

        List<XElement> placemarks = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "SchemaData").ToList();
        foreach (XNode x in placemarks)
        {

        }
```

which simply returns some of the information but not in a format I am able to work with.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to get this data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more searching and a bit of trial and error, I've been able to get the info I need from the following code.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
        List<XElement> placemarks = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "SimpleData").ToList();
        foreach (XElement x in placemarks)
        {

        }
```

"placemarks" can be accessed to get the data.